# PWA Setup with Cloudfront CDN?

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

My web app has a service worker that was working fine before I added integration with Cloudfront CDN.

I'm registering the service worker on the client like so:

```
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('https://www.my-domain-name.com/sw.js')
        .then(() => console.info('service worker registered.'))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error registering serviceWorker: ', error)
        })
```

I get this in the client console logs:

[image]

And Lighthouse is telling me this:

> No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page,
> or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page
> encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest.

I've tried multiple URLs when registering the service worker, including:

- "/sw.js"
- "https://www.my-domain-name.com/sw.js"
- "https://###.cloudfront.net/sw.js"

...but so far none have worked.

What am I missing?

**UPDATES**

I've learned a lot more but still have questions:

- I got a great answer from
  @JeffPosnick to my related SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66770689/service-worker-fetch-error-when-trying-to-load-my-website/66770924#66770924). That explained the errors.
- The URL for "failed to fetch" was the URL specified in my manifest "start_url". **But** I'm still getting a fetch error here, even outside of Lighthouse testing. Anybody know why?
- I unchecked the Lighthouse "Clear Storage" checkbox. Now Lighthouse is saying my service worker is working.

[image]

Theory: when Lighthouse clears storage it blows away the service worker, explaining why I get a failing PWA score from Lighthouse when "Clear Storage" is checked. Is this theory correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally got this all working. In addition to the things I posted in the update to the original post, I also had to find a service worker that would work with React.

I went with [this one](https://github.com/CaptainN/meteor-react-starter/blob/master/public/sw.js).

Now if the network is offline, and I reload the page, I still see my React home page. Nice!