# Service Worker Fetch Error When Trying to Load --- My Website?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, amazon-cloudfront, workbox

I've recently added Cloudfront to my web app. I'm using a WorkBox service worker and getting the error:

> VM7 workbox-strategies.prod.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

I found out from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49383908/364966) to watch the Network tab to find out what resource was causing the problem.

I checked and found out -- it's trying to load my own domain!

[image]

The domain loads in the browser just fine. Why would the service worker be throwing this fetch error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is due to the [new offline support detection](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/improved-pwa-offline-detection/) in Chrome 89+.

If your site has a web app manifest and a service worker, Chrome will automatically simulate an offline connection and then make a request for the `start_url` listed in your web app manifest.

If your service worker uses a network-first strategy for responding to navigation requests, then there may be a failed network request logged in the Network panel, even if the check ultimately succeeds because of a response from the cache.

(The Chrome DevTools team is aware that this can be a bit confusing, and is working on improving how this is reported to developers.)

Comment: Thanks! You seem to know this stuff really well. Could you please take a look at my related SO post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755465/pwa-setup-with-cloudfront-cdn?  My service worker says it is being registered, but Lighthouse is saying "No matching service worker detected."

Comment: Update -- I think I solved it. I'm adding info about it to that post I linked in the last comment.

Comment: Is it correct that Lighthouse will always fail your PWA score if you have "Clear Storage" checked?

Comment: Hey Jeff Posnik,
Thanks a lot for these Informations. I asked a question about a pretty similar problem in this Post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818391/service-worker-the-service-worker-navigation-preload-request-failed-with-networ) but actually I am not sure it is exactly the same problem. I am not getting a failed fetch in Network Tab but an Error Message in the console. Maybe you can take a look at my post and give me a feedback if it's the same issue. And it would be interesting to know if its possible to prevent the error from happening.