# SERVICE WORKER: The service worker navigation preload request failed with network error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED in Chrome 89

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, offline-caching, offlineapps

I have a problem with my Service Worker.

I'm currently implementing offline functionality with an offline.html site to be shown in case of network failure. I have implemented Navigation Preloads as described here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload#activating_navigation_preload

Here is my **install EventListener** were skipWaiting() and initialize new cache

```js
const version = 'v.1.2.3'
const CACHE_NAME = '::static-cache'
const urlsToCache = ['index~offline.html', 'favicon-512.png']

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    self.skipWaiting()
    event.waitUntil(
        caches
            .open(version + CACHE_NAME)
            .then(function(cache) {
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache)
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log('WORKER: install completed')
            })
    )
})
```

Here is my **activate EventListener** were I feature-detect navigationPreload and enable it. Afterwards I check for old caches and delete them

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    console.log('WORKER: activated')
    event.waitUntil(
        (async function() {
            // Feature-detect
            if (self.registration.navigationPreload) {
                // Enable navigation preloads!
                console.log('WORKER: Enable navigation preloads')
                await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable()
            }
        })().then(
            caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
                cacheNames.forEach(function(cacheName) {
                    if (cacheName !== version + CACHE_NAME) {
                        caches.delete(cacheName)
                        console.log(cacheName + ' CACHE deleted')
                    }
                })
            })
        )
    )
})
```

This is my **fetch eventListener**

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    const { request } = event

    // Always bypass for range requests, due to browser bugs
    if (request.headers.has('range')) return
    event.respondWith(
        (async function() {
            // Try to get from the cache:
            const cachedResponse = await caches.match(request)
            if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse

            try {
                const response = await event.preloadResponse
                if (response) return response

                // Otherwise, get from the network
                return await fetch(request)
            } catch (err) {
                // If this was a navigation, show the offline page:
                if (request.mode === 'navigate') {
                    console.log('Err: ',err)
                    console.log('Request: ', request)
                    return caches.match('index~offline.html')
                }

                // Otherwise throw
                throw err
            }
        })()
    )
})
```

**Now my Problem:**
On my local machine on localhost everything just works as it should. If network is offline the index~offline.html page is delivered to the user. If I deploy to my test server everything works as well as expected, except for a strange error-message in Chrome on normal browsing(not offline mode):

```
The service worker navigation preload request failed with network error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED.
```

I logged the error and the request to get more information
**Error:**

```
DOMException: The service worker navigation preload request failed with a network error.
```

**Request:**
[image: Request]

Its strange because somehow index.html is requested no matter which site is loaded.

**Additional Information** this is happening in Chrome 89, in chrome 88 everything seems fine(I checked in browserstack). I just saw there was a change in pwa offline detection in Chrome 89...
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/improved-pwa-offline-detection/

anybody has an idea what the problem might be?

**Update**
I rebuild the problem here so everybody can check it out: https://dreamy-leavitt-bd4f0e.netlify.app/

Answer (score 4):

This error is directly caused by the improved pwa offline detection you linked to:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/improved-pwa-offline-detection/

The browser fakes an offline context and tries to request the start_url of your manifest, e.g. the index.html specified in your https://dreamy-leavitt-bd4f0e.netlify.app/site.webmanifest

This is to make sure that your service worker is actually returning a valid 200 response in this situation, i.e. the valid cached response for your index~offline.html page.

The error you're asking about specifically is from the `await event.preloadResponse` part and it apparently can't be suppressed.

The `await fetch` call produces a similar error but that can be suppressed, just don't `console.log` in the `catch` section.

Hopefully chrome won't show this error from preload responses in future when doing offline pwa detection as it's needlessly confusing.

Comment: As of chrome 90.0.4422.0 this seems to be fixed. I'm not seeing the error anymore.

[This](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/b5ba3cee286d8343a862ab080bf583e29a1c6f7f) is probably the responsible chrome/chromium commit.

Comment: This issue is still happening in Chrome 103